# Trouble while trying to make transparent background for jQuery Mobile dialogs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery Mobile 1.2.0 in my project, and faced with such a problem while trying to make dialog background transparent.
I've modified script from answer at [How to remove page background for Jquery Mobile Dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776475/how-to-remove-page-background-for-jquery-mobile-dialog/) to this one.

```
$(function() {


$('div[data-role="dialog"]').live('pagebeforeshow', function(e, ui) {
    if( !$('[data-role="old-page"]').length ) {

        $('[data-role="page"].ui-page-active')
            .eq(0).clone()
                .attr('data-role','old-page')
                .appendTo('body')
                .addClass('ui-dialog-background-hidden');
    }
    if ( !!$('[data-role="old-page"].ui-dialog-background-hidden').length ) { 
        $('[data-role="old-page"].ui-dialog-background-hidden')
            .removeClass('ui-dialog-background-hidden')
            .addClass("ui-dialog-background ");
    } 
});

$('div[data-role="dialog"]').live('pagehide', function(e, ui) {
    console.log('pageBeforeHide');
    console.log('old-page',$('[data-role="old-page"].ui-dialog-background'))
    if (!$('.ui-dialog.ui-page-active').length) {
        $('[data-role="old-page"].ui-dialog-background')
            .removeClass('ui-dialog-background')
            .addClass('ui-dialog-background-hidden')
            .remove();
    }
});
```

This script saves version of page into the DOM before opening dialog.

And it works "almost" good, accept for the fact that after I go to another page, call dialog and then close it, jQuery Mobile throws error "Cannot call method '_trigger' of undefined" at line 3379.

Any thoughts?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you get that error, any page appears?

Comment: 2Omar: No, after error appeared in console - blank page appeared in browser.

Comment: Not sure if it will solve it, but i think jQuery's `live` method is deprecated. You should use `$(document).on('event', 'selector', function() { ... })`. Maybe that'll also solve the error.